# Anybody using Openhft Chronicle 3.24ea1 in prod env? Would like to know about the challenges/issues faced. Right now seeing classloader related issue

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

We are planning to use Openhft Chronicle 3.24ea1, however facing issue with Chronicle map and that leads to JVM crash on `Ubuntu 22.04.2` with `java-17-openjdk-amd64`

```
*/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/VanillaGlobalMutableState$$Native.java:14: error: cannot access net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.InvalidMarshallableException
public class VanillaGlobalMutableState$$Native implements VanillaGlobalMutableState, Copyable<VanillaGlobalMutableState>, BytesMarshallable, Byteable {
       ^
  class file for net.openhft.chronicle.core.io.InvalidMarshallableException not found
WARN 59061 --- [           main] n.openhft.chronicle.values.ValueModel    : Failed to compile java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.openhft.chronicle.hash.VanillaGlobalMutableState$$Native*
```

It is not able to find `*VanillaGlobalMutableState$$Native*` which was earlier available in packaged core JAR but is not present in 3.24ea1.

As a tactical solution:

1. Generated logs has the Java code for this missing sub-class; we committed that and with that this issue goes away but skeptical of this solution.

Anybody else facing similar issue?

Did you continue till production with chronicle-maps:3.24ea1?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the latest chronicle-bom to determine which versions were tested together if not, use it for your build.

The latest version is: https://search.maven.org/search?q=chronicle-bom currently 2.24ea80

At the time of writing, Chronicle-Map 2.24ea3 uses Chronicle-Core 2.24ea26 (which has the class it couldn't find)